Vue.js secure (wss) websocket add trustore
I vant to establish a secure websocket connection between my Vue.js app and my Java server. I have built a working Java client first for testing purposes and I initialize my client SSL context like so:
KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path + fileName);
truststore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(truststore);

return SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(trustManagerFactory).build();

Before adding a handler built using this SSL context to the pipeline.
How cal I do the same in my Vue.js app to establish a secure connexion? I am using the ws library.
I created my Keystore/Truststore using keytool like described here: https://nikoskatsanos.com/blog/2022/01/netty-websocket-ssl/ so I have a .cert file, a truststore .jks file and a keystore .jks file.
